# How to update the values or range for a graph with multiple series?

Tags: excel, charts, vba

I have a spreadsheet that has several charts. I house the data for the charts on 3 other sheets. I am trying, so far without success, to update the charts to cover additional data as I add it.

I have tried several things based on what I've seen around on the web. I've tried setting a range like

```
Set SourceRange1 = Split(Join((GetArray(Sheets(1).Range("P6:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(1).Cells(6, Sheets(1).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "6"))), "|"), "|")
Set SourceRange2 = GetArray(Sheets(2).Range("P6:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(2).Cells(6, Sheets(2).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "6")))
Set SourceRange3 = Application.Union(Worksheets(3).Range("P5", Sheets(3).Cells(5, Sheets(1).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)), Sheets(3).Range("P6", Sheets(3).Cells(6, Sheets(3).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))).Value
```

and then assigning it to the chart like this:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = SourceRange1
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = SourceRange2
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Values = SourceRange3
```

This gives me the range `P5:x5` currently, but it doesn't set the chart series.

Just for reference, the `GetArray` is a function that I created:

```
Function GetArray(Range1 As Range)
    Dim Test() As String, cell As Range, i As Integer
    i = 0
    ReDim Test(0)
    For Each cell In Range1
        ReDim Preserve Test(i)
        Test(i) = cell.Value
        i = i + 1
    Next cell
    GetArray = Test
End Function
```

And so it the GetLetterFromNumber:

```
Function GetLetterFromNumber(Number)
    GetLetterFromNumber = Split(Cells(1, Number).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
End Function
```

With the current setup like the `Set SourceRange1`, I get a

> Compile error: Can't assign to array

I get the same error with both of the others as well. I have `SourceRange1-3` setup like `Dim SourceRange1()`

If I set them up like `Dim SourceRange1` then I get:

> Run-time error '13':
>
> Type Mismatch
>   On all three.

If I assign the `SeriesCollection` directly like:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = GetArray(Sheets(1).Range("P6:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(1).Cells(6, Sheets(1).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "6"))
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = GetArray(Sheets(2).Range("P6:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(2).Cells(6, Sheets(2).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "6"))
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Values = GetArray(Sheets(3).Range("P6:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(3).Cells(6, Sheets(3).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "6"))
```

The it assigns 0 to all the values when for `SeriesCollection(1)` they should be:

```
(20,30,40,50,60,10,20,30,40)
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, I just don't know what. If I've missed putting something in my description let me know and I can add it.

Otherwise, all the help I can get will be appreciated.

Comment: If you try `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=" & SourceRange1.Address(True, True, xlA1, xlExternal)` , is it working ?

Comment: I'm not able to get a range assigned to the variable SourceRange1, but I tried this `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=" & Sheets(2).Range("P6:" & GetLetterFromNumber(Sheets(2).Cells(6, Sheets(2).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) & "6").Address(True, True, xlAl, xlExternal)` and it assigned the values. I'm testing still to see if this answers my question.

Comment: ok, let me know

Comment: It works perfectly! Put this as an answer and I'll check it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the `Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values` to be connected dynamically with the `Range` use something like the line below (assuming your `SourceRange1` range is defined correclty):

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=" & SourceRange1.Address(True, True, xlA1, xlExternal)
```

When working with Charts you might also consider using:

```
Dim Cht as Chart
Dim Ser as Series
Set Cht = ActiveChart 
Set Ser = Cht.SeriesCollection(1)

With Ser
    .Values = "=" & SourceRange1.Address(True, True, xlA1, xlExternal)
End With
```